# AUCTeX can't find MiKTeX

Tags: emacs, miktex, auctex

I've installed AUCTeX in my copy of Emacs but AUCTeX can't find MiKTeX (which I've already installed). I get the following error when I do C-c C-c RET:

```
ERROR: AUCTeX cannot find a working TeX distribution.
Make sure you have one and that TeX binaries are in PATH environment variable.
If you are using OS X El Capitan or later
Remember to add /Library/TeX/texbin/ to your PATH
```

There is no /Library/TeX directory on my computer after installing MiKTeX. How do I proceed? Thanks

I’m running Emacs Version 28.1 (9.0) on a Mac mini M1 with macOS Monterey 12.4.

Answer (score 0):

On my side, `texbin` is located at `/Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/texbin` and I'm not sure whether thing is different on M1.

Besides, I suggest to use [exec-path-from-shell](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell) to make Emacs use the $PATH set up by the user's shell.